# How can I get the email configuration from the DB?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

What I need is to take the email configuration like `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT`, etc. From my database and then pass that values to the email configuration in the `settings.py` file. Is this possible? and if is, how can I do it?

Comment: You can not to this, since settings.py is the first thing that django loads up to set your running env. Django can not access database at this point.

Comment: At some point I tried to créate a custom `EmailBacked` to take the values from the database but that didn't work, but I don't know if I do wrong my custom `EmailBackend` or if in the custom backend that can't be done, do you know a way to do what I´m trying to do?

Comment: There is a long way to achieve this, but not via django. You cannot use any part of django or its functionality since the settings.py file isn't loaded yet. If you are comfortable working a little outside django, i will proceed to work upon its methodology (will involve environment variable settings, custom raw SQL query using python, whatever your db is, it's direct working with python)

Comment: I was thinking in use variables in the __init__ to store my queries results and use that variables as global variables to can use them in `setting.py`, something like that?

Comment: and by 'init', you exactly mean how and where?

Comment: In the `__init__.py` file from my App. Do something like `mail_conf = MailConfModel.objects.get(default=true)` and then in `settings.py` set the configuration like `EMAIL_HOST_USER = mail_conf.email_host_user` or that can´t be done?

Comment: As i said before you cannot use django, since it hasn't started yet. Here you are using django's ORM.

Comment: I can try directly with Python as you said

Comment: yup, surely you can do that. Write sql scripts with python, and they will work just fine. Just don't use anything related to django.

Comment: Thanks for the info =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualy this isn't so hard to do if you use [django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#smtp-backend) like this:

```
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend

backend = EmailBackend(host = server.host, server.port, server.username, serer.password)
```

Once you create a backend like this. You have two options on how to send the message. The first is you can call the send_messages() method on it send your messages (or message). The second is you can tell [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage) to use it as the connection.
 And where does server.whatever come from? The database of course.

```
class EmailServer(models.Model):
   host = models.CharFields()
   ....
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

Although this is more than six years old this gave me the right idea and it still works with Django 4.1. I also need the use_tls setting, so my setup looks like this:

```
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend


# Get email settings from DB, e.g.
settings = Setting.objects.filter(name='settings').first()

# Custom email backend
backend = EmailBackend(
    host=settings.email_host,
    use_tls=settings.email_use_tls,
    port=settings.email_port,
    username=settings.email_host_user,
    password=settings.email_host_password_enc,
)
```

You can also continue using Django's send_mail method, you might have been using before, if you pass in the custom backend for 'connection' (I had been using the following Thread class and just added the custom backend):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from threading import Thread    


thread = MailThread(subject, mail_text, noreply, email)
thread.start()


class MailThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, subject, mail_text, noreply, to_email):
        super(MailThread, self).__init__()
        self.subject = subject
        self.to_email = to_email
        self.noreply = noreply
        self.mail_text = mail_text

    # run method is automatically executed on thread.start()
    def run(self):
        send_mail(
            self.subject,
            self.mail_text,
            self.noreply,
            [self.email],
            fail_silently=False,
            connection=backend
        )
```